# Python re and regex: search() doesn't doesn't match identical strings with non-ASCII characters

Tags: python, regex, unicode

Trying to get re or regex to match a non-ASCII string with itself. I've read the other posts regarding non-ASCII/unicode and tried adding the unicode flag, to no avail:

```
# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 14 2012, 08:58:41) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> import regex
>>> s1 = 'wow'
>>> s2 = 'ℛℯα∂α♭ℓℯ ♭ʊ☂ η☺т Ѧ$☾ℐℐ'
>>> print(s2)
ℛℯα∂α♭ℓℯ ♭ʊ☂ η☺т Ѧ$☾ℐℐ
>>> re.search(s1,s1)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f0ce27c38b8>
>>> re.search(s2,s2)
>>> type(s2)
<type 'str'>
>>> us2 = unicode(s2,'utf-8')
>>> us2
u'\u211b\u212f\u03b1\u2202\u03b1\u266d\u2113\u212f \u266d\u028a\u2602 \u03b7\u263a\u0442 \u0466$\u263e\u2110\u2110'
>>> re.search(us2,us2,re.UNICODE)
>>> regex.search(s2,s2)
>>> regex.search(us2,us2,regex.UNICODE)
>>>
```

I hope I'm missing something obvious. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: My guess is those characters are being treated as special characters. Perhaps you need to escape them?

Comment: Do you see `$` in the `us2`? It will surely prevent matching since there cannot be anything after the end of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that as a regex pattern, `s2` has a `at at_end` pattern inside it.

```
In [62]: re.compile(s2, re.DEBUG)
literal 226
literal 132
literal 155
...
at at_end
...
literal 226
literal 132
literal 144
```

This is because, as a utf-8 encoded string, `s2` is

```
In [61]: s2 = 'ℛℯα∂α♭ℓℯ ♭ʊ☂ η☺т Ѧ$☾ℐℐ'
In [72]: s2
Out[72]: '\xe2\x84\x9b\xe2\x84\xaf\xce\xb1\xe2\x88\x82\xce\xb1\xe2\x99\xad\xe2\x84\x93\xe2\x84\xaf \xe2\x99\xad\xca\x8a\xe2\x98\x82 \xce\xb7\xe2\x98\xba\xd1\x82 \xd1\xa6$\xe2\x98\xbe\xe2\x84\x90\xe2\x84\x90'
```

and notice there is a  `$` in `s2`:

```
In [75]: '$' in s2
Out[75]: True
```

To prevent that `$` from being interpreted as an `at at_end` pattern, use `re.escape` to escape all non-alphanumeric characters in the pattern:

```
In [67]: pat = re.compile(re.escape(s2))

In [68]: pat.search(s2)
Out[68]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x7feb6b44dd98>
```

---

The same goes for escaping the unicode pattern:

```
In [78]: us2 = unicode(s2,'utf-8')

In [79]: re.search(re.escape(us2), us2)
Out[79]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x7feb6b44ded0>
```

since

```
In [81]: u'$' in us2
Out[81]: True
```